# "android:activatedBackgroundIndicator" not changing background color

Tags: java, android, listview, attr

I had this working before, but for some reason I can't get the background color to change anymore. I am using a cab and standard listview with a multiChoiceModeListener.

Listview in mainActivity layout:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Listview item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:layout_height="80dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lvNum"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="100"
    android:textSize="42dp"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lvName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Counter Name"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:paddingRight="140dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lvNum" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/subtractButt"
    android:text="-"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/addButt"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addButt" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/addButt"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Styles (I recently added the second theme, but I have erased anywhere it is used)

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_activated_background</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentDark</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_activated_background</item>
</style>
```

list_activated_background (Changing the colors has no effect)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Thanks for any help, I'm completely stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching the activatedBackgroundIndicator in my custom adapter i added:

```
vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_activated_background);
```